# Dynamic menus and submenus not shown in vue3 navigation bar

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, tailwind-css, inertiajs

i have developed a laravel intertia vue project to create dashbaord using th following method:

`composer require laraveldaily/larastarters --dev`

`php artisan larastarters:install`

Selected option 1, Laravel Breeze & Inertia (Tailwind)

Now I pass a shared variable in HandleInertiaRequests by calculating the list of menus and submenus for the user.
I pass the data as menulist.

I have the following **Navigation.vue** file . I try to add dynamic menus and submenus.
See the following code:

```
    <template>
    <div :class="$page.props.showingMobileMenu ? 'block' : 'hidden'" @click="$page.props.showingMobileMenu = false"
         class="fixed inset-0 z-20 bg-black opacity-50 transition-opacity lg:hidden"></div>

    <div :class="$page.props.showingMobileMenu ? 'translate-x-0 ease-out' : '-translate-x-full ease-in'"
         class="overflow-y-auto fixed inset-y-0 left-0 z-30 w-64 bg-gray-900 transition duration-300 transform lg:translate-x-0 lg:static lg:inset-0">
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center mt-8">
            <div class="flex items-center">
                <svg class="w-12 h-12" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path
                        d="M364.61 390.213C304.625 450.196 207.37 450.196 147.386 390.213C117.394 360.22 102.398 320.911 102.398 281.6C102.398 242.291 117.394 202.981 147.386 172.989C147.386 230.4 153.6 281.6 230.4 307.2C230.4 256 256 102.4 294.4 76.7999C320 128 334.618 142.997 364.608 172.989C394.601 202.981 409.597 242.291 409.597 281.6C409.597 320.911 394.601 360.22 364.61 390.213Z"
                        fill="#4C51BF" stroke="#4C51BF" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                        stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path
                        d="M201.694 387.105C231.686 417.098 280.312 417.098 310.305 387.105C325.301 372.109 332.8 352.456 332.8 332.8C332.8 313.144 325.301 293.491 310.305 278.495C295.309 263.498 288 256 275.2 230.4C256 243.2 243.201 320 243.201 345.6C201.694 345.6 179.2 332.8 179.2 332.8C179.2 352.456 186.698 372.109 201.694 387.105Z"
                        fill="white"/>
                </svg>

                <span class="mx-2 text-2xl font-semibold text-white">Dashboard</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav class="mt-10" x-data="{ isMultiLevelMenuOpen: false }">
            <nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="route().current('dashboard')">
                <template #icon>
                    <svg class="w-6 h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                         stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                              d="M11 3.055A9.001 9.001 0 1020.945 13H11V3.055z"/>
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                              d="M20.488 9H15V3.512A9.025 9.025 0 0120.488 9z"/>
                    </svg>
                </template>
                Dashboard
            </nav-link>

            <nav-link :href="route('users.index')" :active="route().current('users.index')">
                <template #icon>
                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                              d="M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </template>
                Users
            </nav-link>

            <nav-link :href="route('about')" :active="route().current('about')">
                <template #icon>
                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                         stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path
                            d="M4 5a1 1 0 011-1h14a1 1 0 011 1v2a1 1 0 01-1 1H5a1 1 0 01-1-1V5zM4 13a1 1 0 011-1h6a1 1 0 011 1v6a1 1 0 01-1 1H5a1 1 0 01-1-1v-6zM16 13a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v6a1 1 0 01-1 1h-2a1 1 0 01-1-1v-6z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </template>
                About us
            </nav-link>

            <a class="flex items-center mt-4 py-2 px-6 text-gray-100" href="#" @click="showingTwoLevelMenu = !showingTwoLevelMenu">
                <svg class="w-6 h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                          d="M17 14v6m-3-3h6M6 10h2a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2zm10 0h2a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2h-2a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2zM6 20h2a2 2 0 002-2v-2a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2z"></path>
                </svg>
                <span class="mx-3">Two-level menu</span>
            </a>
            <transition
                enter-to-class="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
                enter-from-class="max-h-0 opacity-25"
                leave-from-class="opacity-100 max-h-xl"
                leave-to-class="max-h-0 opacity-0">
                <div v-show="showingTwoLevelMenu">
                    <ul class="overflow-hidden p-2 mx-4 mt-2 space-y-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-inner"
                        aria-label="submenu">
                        <li class="px-2 py-1 transition-colors duration-150">
                            <Link class="w-full" :href="route('dashboard')">Child menu1</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li class="px-2 py-1 transition-colors duration-150">
                            <Link class="w-full" :href="route('dashboard')">Child menu2</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </transition>
            <div v-for="(submenus, menuName) in menusubmenu" :key="menuName">
     
      <a class="flex items-center mt-4 py-2 px-6 text-gray-100" href="#" @click="showingTwoLevelMenu = !showingTwoLevelMenu">
                <svg class="w-6 h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                          d="M17 14v6m-3-3h6M6 10h2a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2zm10 0h2a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2h-2a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2zM6 20h2a2 2 0 002-2v-2a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2z"></path>
                </svg>
                <span class="mx-3">{{ menuName }}</span>
            </a>
            <transition
                enter-to-class="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
                enter-from-class="max-h-0 opacity-25"
                leave-from-class="opacity-100 max-h-xl"
                leave-to-class="max-h-0 opacity-0">
               <!----<div v-show="menuVisibility[0].value">-->
                   <div>
                    <ul class="overflow-hidden p-2 mx-4 mt-2 space-y-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-inner"
                        aria-label="submenu">
                        <li>item</li>
                        <!--<li class="px-2 py-1 transition-colors duration-150" v-for="submenu in submenus.submenus" :key="submenu">{{ submenu }}</li>
                        -->
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </transition>
      
    </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
import { onMounted,computed } from 'vue';
import NavLink from '@/Components/NavLink.vue';
import { Link,usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { ref } from 'vue'



export default {
    components: {
        NavLink,
        Link,
    },


    setup() {
        let showingTwoLevelMenu = ref(false);
        let menusubmenu = ref(false);
        let menuVisibility = {};

        onMounted(() => {
            let page = usePage();
  let sharedata = computed(() => page.props.sharedata);
 let menulist = computed(() => page.props.menulist); // Assign the computed value to menulist.value        console.log('Component mounted with sharedata:', sharedata.value);
  /*menulist.value.forEach(menuName => {
            menuVisibility[menuName] = ref(false);
        });  */    
        menusubmenu=menulist.value
        console.log(sharedata.value);
  console.log(menusubmenu);
        });

        return {
            showingTwoLevelMenu,menusubmenu,
             menuVisibility
            
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

My menulist has the following data:

```
"User": {
    "submenus": [
      "My Profile",
      "Change Password"
    ]
  },
  "Projects": {
    "submenus": [
      "View Projects"
    ]
  },
  "Clients": {
    "submenus": [
      "View Clients"
    ]
  },
  "Tickets Inbox": {
    "submenus": [
      "All Tickets",
      "New Tickets",
      "Processed Tickets",
      "Change Requests",
      "Self Assign Ticket"
    ]
  },
  "Dashboard": {
    "submenus": [
      "Dashboard"
    ]
  }
```

But i dont see the dynamic menus and submenus in the vue navbar

Answer (score 0):

i edited the code and it is working though i couldnt get the show/unshow option of dynamic submenus when i click on the menu. The updated code:

```
<template>
    <div :class="$page.props.showingMobileMenu ? 'block' : 'hidden'" @click="$page.props.showingMobileMenu = false"
         class="fixed inset-0 z-20 bg-black opacity-50 transition-opacity lg:hidden"></div>

    <div :class="$page.props.showingMobileMenu ? 'translate-x-0 ease-out' : '-translate-x-full ease-in'"
         class="overflow-y-auto fixed inset-y-0 left-0 z-30 w-64 bg-gray-900 transition duration-300 transform lg:translate-x-0 lg:static lg:inset-0">
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center mt-8">
            <div class="flex items-center">
                <svg class="w-12 h-12" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path
                        d="M364.61 390.213C304.625 450.196 207.37 450.196 147.386 390.213C117.394 360.22 102.398 320.911 102.398 281.6C102.398 242.291 117.394 202.981 147.386 172.989C147.386 230.4 153.6 281.6 230.4 307.2C230.4 256 256 102.4 294.4 76.7999C320 128 334.618 142.997 364.608 172.989C394.601 202.981 409.597 242.291 409.597 281.6C409.597 320.911 394.601 360.22 364.61 390.213Z"
                        fill="#4C51BF" stroke="#4C51BF" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                        stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path
                        d="M201.694 387.105C231.686 417.098 280.312 417.098 310.305 387.105C325.301 372.109 332.8 352.456 332.8 332.8C332.8 313.144 325.301 293.491 310.305 278.495C295.309 263.498 288 256 275.2 230.4C256 243.2 243.201 320 243.201 345.6C201.694 345.6 179.2 332.8 179.2 332.8C179.2 352.456 186.698 372.109 201.694 387.105Z"
                        fill="white"/>
                </svg>

                <span class="mx-2 text-2xl font-semibold text-white">Dashboard</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav class="mt-10" x-data="{ isMultiLevelMenuOpen: false }">
            <nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="route().current('dashboard')">
                <template #icon>
                    <svg class="w-6 h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                         stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                              d="M11 3.055A9.001 9.001 0 1020.945 13H11V3.055z"/>
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                              d="M20.488 9H15V3.512A9.025 9.025 0 0120.488 9z"/>
                    </svg>
                </template>
                Dashboard
            </nav-link>

            <nav-link :href="route('users.index')" :active="route().current('users.index')">
                <template #icon>
                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                              d="M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </template>
                Users
            </nav-link>

            <nav-link :href="route('about')" :active="route().current('about')">
                <template #icon>
                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                         stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path
                            d="M4 5a1 1 0 011-1h14a1 1 0 011 1v2a1 1 0 01-1 1H5a1 1 0 01-1-1V5zM4 13a1 1 0 011-1h6a1 1 0 011 1v6a1 1 0 01-1 1H5a1 1 0 01-1-1v-6zM16 13a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v6a1 1 0 01-1 1h-2a1 1 0 01-1-1v-6z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </template>
                About us
            </nav-link>

            <a class="flex items-center mt-4 py-2 px-6 text-gray-100" href="#" @click="showingTwoLevelMenu = !showingTwoLevelMenu">
                <svg class="w-6 h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                          d="M17 14v6m-3-3h6M6 10h2a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2zm10 0h2a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2h-2a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2zM6 20h2a2 2 0 002-2v-2a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2z"></path>
                </svg>
                <span class="mx-3">Two-level menu</span>
            </a>
            <transition
                enter-to-class="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
                enter-from-class="max-h-0 opacity-25"
                leave-from-class="opacity-100 max-h-xl"
                leave-to-class="max-h-0 opacity-0">
                <div v-show="showingTwoLevelMenu">
                    <ul class="overflow-hidden p-2 mx-4 mt-2 space-y-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-inner"
                        aria-label="submenu">
                        <li class="px-2 py-1 transition-colors duration-150">
                            <Link class="w-full" :href="route('dashboard')">Child menu1</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li class="px-2 py-1 transition-colors duration-150">
                            <Link class="w-full" :href="route('dashboard')">Child menu2</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </transition>
            <div v-for="(submenus, menu) in menusubmenu" :key="menu">
     
      <a class="flex items-center mt-4 py-2 px-6 text-gray-100" href="#" @click="menuVisibility[0].value = !menuVisibility[0].value">
        <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                              d="M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"></path>
                    </svg>
                <span class="mx-3">{{ menu}}</span>
            </a>
            <transition
                enter-to-class="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
                enter-from-class="max-h-0 opacity-25"
                leave-from-class="opacity-100 max-h-xl"
                leave-to-class="max-h-0 opacity-0">
               <div v-show="menuVisibility[0]">
                  
                    <ul class="overflow-hidden p-2 mx-4 mt-2 space-y-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-inner"
                        aria-label="submenu">
                        
                        <li class="px-2 py-1 transition-colors duration-150" v-for="submenu in submenus.submenus" :key="submenu">{{ submenu }}</li>
                        
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </transition>
      
    </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
import { onMounted,computed } from 'vue';
import NavLink from '@/Components/NavLink.vue';
import { Link,usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { ref } from 'vue'


export default {
    components: {
        NavLink,
        Link,
    },


    setup() {
        let showingTwoLevelMenu = ref(false);
        let menusubmenu = ref(false);
        let menuVisibility = {};
              

        onMounted(() => {
            let page = usePage();
  let sharedata = computed(() => page.props.sharedata);
 let menulist = computed(() => page.props.menulist); // Assign the computed value to menulist.value        console.log('Component mounted with sharedata:', sharedata.value);
  /*menulist.value.forEach(menuName => {
            menuVisibility[menuName] = ref(false);
        });  */    
        menusubmenu.value=JSON.parse(menulist.value)
        let i=0
        Object.keys(menusubmenu.value).forEach(menu => {
            menuVisibility[i++] = ref(false);
      });
        
       // menusubmenu.forEach((menuName)=>console.log(menuName));
       // console.log(sharedata.value);
  //console.log(menusubmenu.value);
        });

        return {
            showingTwoLevelMenu,menusubmenu,
             menuVisibility
            
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Anyone can find a solution to get the show/unshow of dynamic submenus